# Cannot select option value in functional test

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing

A form includes a select option for ethnicity:

```
Ethnicity: <select id="household_members_0_ethnicity" name="household[members][0][ethnicity]" class="smallform">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="2">AfrAm</option>
<option value="3">Asian</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Cau</option>
<option value="6">HaPI</option>
<option value="4">Hisp</option>
<option value="5">NtvAm</option>
<option value="7">Oth</option>
<option value="8">Unk</option>
</select>
```

The functional test contains 
`$form["household[members][0][ethnicity]"]->select(6);`

and returns

> InvalidArgumentException: Input "household[members][0][ethnicity]"
>   cannot take "6" as a value (possible values: ).

Note that possible values is empty.  I have tried testing with `select("6")` and `select("HaPI")` and combinations of other options, all to no avail.

Fwiw, there is a similar select for gender and `$form["household[members][0][sex]"]->select('Male');` does NOT throw an exception.

I have also tried entering `$form()` values in array form with no change in results.

Only difference between gender and ethnicity fields is that gender is an explicit choice field, ethnicity is an entity field.

`$form["household[members][0][ethnicity]"]->availableOptionValues();` returns an empty array;

`$form["household[members][0][sex]"]->availableOptionValues();` returns an array of values and options;

Comment: So the real problem is why there is no option selectable? Since this is an entity, does `ethnicity` have values in the database?

Comment: @A.L Most assuredly the database is populated - that's where the displayed options come from.  They were not "hard-wired".

Comment: Ok, but you have the message *(possible values: ).* so there is no option to select.

Comment: @A.L Hence my question - how can I select an option that ought to be available, is available in the page source, yet is not available in a functional test?  The answer probably lies in behind the "why is possible values empty?" question.

Comment: Is the option available in the source in the `test` environment? I suggest to edit your question to focus on the fact that there is no option during the test. Once you'll have fixed this problem you'll be able to select it easily.

Comment: You can dump the form to check what are the right names of the fields maybe it can help

Comment: @A.L You were right at the beginning - I had totally forgotten that I was using a sqlite test database.  The only way to populate the database is to build the fixture,  Thanks for planting the seeds of doubt. Post this as a solution and I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> InvalidArgumentException: Input "household[members][0][ethnicity]" cannot take "6" as a value (possible values: ).

The error message should display the list of possible values, not *(possible values: )*. You have to check that in the `test` environment, this field is populated with the records of the `ethnicity` entity. According to your comment you use a SQLite database, so you have to check that your data fixtures insert some data for the `ethnicity` entity.